# System.Threading.Tasks - Cannot catch exception using Task.WaitAll()

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run some tasks in parallel which each return a value. Once they are all complete I want to utilize those returned results. The issue I am having is capturing the exception if one of tasks throws one.

Following what I've seen on some other SO questions I think this simplified code below should work. When I run it in visual studio it however my exception does not get handled.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int[] ids = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            Test t = new Test();
             t.Process(ids);
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        public void Process(int[] ids)
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task<Tuple<int, bool>>>(ids.Count());
            foreach (int id in ids)
            {
                //The task will run at an indeterminate time so create a copy of id as it may have a new value assigned before that occurs 
                int i = id;
                var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(i));
                tasks.Add(task);
            }
            try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var innerEx in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(innerEx);
                }

            }
            foreach (var t in tasks)
            {
                Tuple<int, bool> result = t.Result;

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - success = {1}", result.Item1, result.Item2));
            }
        }

        private Tuple<int, bool> DoWork(int i)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Processing {0}", i));
            Thread.Sleep(i * 500);
            if (i == 3)
            {
                //This exception does not get caught.
                throw new Exception(string.Format("exception thrown on: {0}", i));
            }
            return new Tuple<int, bool>(i, true);
        }
    }
```

What I am expecting should get printed (order might be changed due to things running in parallel):

Processing 1
Processing 2
Processing 3
Processing 4
exception throw on: 3
1 - success = True
2 - success = True
4 - success = True

Am I completely misunderstanding how Task.WaitAll is meant to work?

Comment: Yes - You need to implement cancellation if you want to stop a running task http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx otherwise how would they stop in 'good state'?

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not.  However, you are observing the exception twice.  Task.WaitAll will throw the exception, and your code will output the information on the exception.  Then, you'll get the exception again when you fetch the result of that task from t.Result (tasks still contains the task that threw the exception).

You have have at least two choices to solve this issue:

1. Remove the task that generates the exception from your list of
   tasks.
2. Remove your Task.WaitAll and just go through your foreach on
   tasks with the expectation that t.Result will block until that Task
   completes (or throw an exception if that Task throws an exception).

Here's the update for #2:

```
public void Process(int[] ids)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<Tuple<int, bool>>>(ids.Count());
    foreach (int id in ids)
    {
        //The task will run at an indeterminate time so create a copy of id as it may have a new value assigned before that occurs 
        int i = id;
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(i));
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    foreach (var t in tasks)
    {
        try
        {
            Tuple<int, bool> result = t.Result;

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - success = {1}", result.Item1, result.Item2));
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            foreach (var innerEx in ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(innerEx.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use exceptions for control flow. Examine Task.Exception. Don't make Result throw if you know it is going to throw. Still, +1.

Comment: Be careful with Task.Exception.  It only reports the exception if it has already occurred -- it is not a blocking call.  Adding a check for t.Exception being null before accessing t.Result does not change the behavior of the program in the example.

Comment: WaitAll will wait for everything, but I overlooked that your code does not use it. You're right, then.